# Insert value to df1 from df2 if df1 matches 2 columns in df2

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df1` like this:

```
ID1 <- c("AAA" , "CCD" , "AAA", "ABC", "AAA", "ABC", "ZZZ")
year1 <- c(2009,2008,2012,2012,2000,2012,2005)
df1 <- data.frame(ID1,year1)
df1

  ID1 year1
1 AAA  2009
2 CCD  2008
3 AAA  2012
4 ABC  2012
5 AAA  2000
6 ABC  2012
7 ZZZ  2005
```

Then, I have a dataframe `df2` like this:

```
ID2 <- c("CCC","AAA","AAA","CCD","AAA","ABC","AAA","ABC","ABC","CCD")
year2 <- c(2005,2010,2012,2008,2009,2012,2000,2012,2004,2008)
xp <- c(5,6,7,8,5,4,3,4,3,8)
df2 <- data.frame(ID2,year2,xp)
df2

   ID2 year2 xp
1  CCC  2005  5
2  AAA  2010  6
3  AAA  2012  7
4  CCD  2008  8
5  AAA  2009  5
6  ABC  2012  4
7  AAA  2000  3
8  ABC  2012  4
9  ABC  2004  3
10 CCD  2008  8
```

I want to add the value of the column `xp` to `df1` if `df1$ID1 == df2$ID2` & `df1$year1 == df2$year2`. I tried:

```
df1$xp <- df2$xp[match(df1$ID1, df2$ID2) & match(df1$year1, df2$year2)]
```

which won't work. The result should be:

```
  ID1 year1 xp
1 AAA  2009  5
2 CCD  2008  8
3 AAA  2012  7
4 ABC  2012  4
5 AAA  2000  3
6 ABC  2012  4
7 ZZZ  2005 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, based on `dplyr::left_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID1" = "ID2", "year1" = "year2")) %>% 
  distinct

#>   ID1 year1 xp
#> 1 AAA  2009  5
#> 2 CCD  2008  8
#> 3 AAA  2012  7
#> 4 ABC  2012  4
#> 5 AAA  2000  3
#> 6 ZZZ  2005 NA
```

---

Or using `base R`:

```r
unique(merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("ID1", "year1"), by.y = c("ID2", "year2"), 
    all.x = T))

#>    ID1 year1 xp
#> 1  AAA  2000  3
#> 2  AAA  2009  5
#> 3  AAA  2012  7
#> 4  ABC  2012  4
#> 8  CCD  2008  8
#> 10 ZZZ  2005 NA
```

Comment: You are missing a row in the expected output, which I think is because of the duplicates in `df2`. So, if you run `distinct` on `df2` in the join, then that should get to the OP's expected output. `left_join(df1, distinct(df2), by = c("ID1" = "ID2", "year1" = "year2"))`. Likewise, moving the `unique` in the base R should fix that as well (but didn't test that one).

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewGB, for having commented my answer. I had noticed that, but I am not sure the OP's expected output is really the wanted expected output, as `ABC  2012  4` repeats once (intentionally or by mistake?)

Comment: I added the duplicate in `df2` intentionally because such duplicates can appear in my data theoretically. Actually there were no duplicates of that kind in my data, so in this case  `left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID1" = "ID2", "year1" = "year2")) %>% distinct` worked perfectly. Good to know @AndrewGB

Comment: @OK_4711 In your expected output above, you have a duplicate `ABC  2012  4`.  So, my comment above is working around that to keep that duplicate / return all rows from `df1`. However, if you don't want duplicate rows, then applying `distinct` or `unique` will remove those rows. I also updated my answer to remove the duplicate row, so that both are there, depending on your needs. But either way, glad that you have a working solution for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), on = c("ID1" = "ID2", "year1" = "year2"), xp := i.xp]
```

**Output**

```
   ID1 year1 xp
1: AAA  2009  5
2: CCD  2008  8
3: AAA  2012  7
4: ABC  2012  4
5: AAA  2000  3
6: ABC  2012  4
7: ZZZ  2005 NA
```

Or if you only want to keep the unique rows, as mentioned above, then you can use `unique`:

```
df1 <-
  unique(setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), on = c("ID1" = "ID2", "year1" = "year2"), xp := i.xp])
```

*Output*

```
   ID1 year1 xp
1: AAA  2009  5
2: CCD  2008  8
3: AAA  2012  7
4: ABC  2012  4
5: AAA  2000  3
6: ZZZ  2005 NA
```